# How to change the nonce between transactions in web3j?

Tags: web3j, java

I have this line of code where it registers a transaction in blockchain. And I wanted to know how I can make the nonce different between the transactions?

```
txhash = careercertificate
            .createCertificate(id, fecha, nombre, rutalumno, instituto, rutinstituto, titulo, totalhash, fechatitulacion, registronumber, codigoV)
            .send().getTransactionHash();
```

Comment: I think the nonce is automatically managed for you, each time you call the send() it check the last nonce and increment it by 1, therefore you should give a lot of time between each send() or it will conflict sometimes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood, the Web3J SmartContract Java Wrapper calculates the nonce by getting the number of transactions `getTransactionCount` for the account (`credential`).

```
EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = web3.ethGetTransactionCount(credentials.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).send();
BigInteger nonce =  ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();
```

If for some reasons, you want to manually set the nonce (because you're sending multiple parallel transactions I guess), it is not an easy task and you gonna have to replicate what web3j is doing behind the scene.

**i. Some constants**

```
    final String privateKey = "48c2210576121c68883b2f96ae82cdf5fd845d99f4243b9c44651316accaac97"; // Dummy private key !!!
    final String contractAddress = "0x5e417E6d4e15471912743e1173D5fD3a3617aD9f"; // Smart contract after deployment on Ganache
    final BigInteger gasLimit = new BigInteger("6721975"); // Block gas limit (Ganache)
    final BigInteger gasPrice = new BigInteger("20000000000"); // 20 gwei - Gas Price (Ganache)
```

**ii. Connect to the node and initiate web3j**

```
// Connect to the node
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService());  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
```

**iii. Read the private key**

```
// Read Private Key
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privateKey)
```

**iv. Calculate the transaction data**

A transaction is constituted of several information like `from` account, `to` account, `value`, `gasPrice`, `gasLimit`, `nonce` and `data`. `data` in the  case of a smart contact represents the encoding of the function, the parameter types and the parameters.

You can calculate `data` like this:

```
// Extract the  function from the Smart Contract wrapper generated by web3j cli
final Function function = new Function(
        Counter.FUNC_INCREMENT, 
        Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
        Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());

// Encode to data
String data = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
```

**v. Choose a nonce**

Based on whatever you want, select a nonce (*/!\ must be greater than the nonce of the last transaction on this account*)

```
// Calculate nonce 
(...)
BigInteger nonce =  new BigInteger("101");
```

**vi. Prepare the transaction**

```
// Prepare transaction
RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(
        nonce,
        gasPrice,
        gasLimit,
        contractAddress,
        BigInteger.ZERO, // No Value
        data);
```

**vii. Send the transaction**

```
// Transaction manager
RawTransactionManager transactionManager = new RawTransactionManager(web3, credentials);
EthSendTransaction transaction = transactionManager.signAndSend(rawTransaction);

log.debug("transaction hash = {}", transaction.getTransactionHash());
```

---

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/blob/master/66277-how-to-change-the-nonce-between-transactions-in-web3j/src/test/java/net/consensys/gjeanmart/TestCounter.java):